# JSF Redirect to requested page after login

Tags: jsf-2

i wrote a login for my JSF project and defined a little private section to test it.

This is my LoginFilter:

```
@WebFilter("/private/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    private NavigationService navigationService = null;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;

        String originalURL = req.getRequestURL().toString();

        if(req.getQueryString() != null) {
            originalURL += "?" + req.getQueryString();
        }

        User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");

        if(user != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("originalURL", originalURL);

            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + navigationService.toLogin());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

This is my LoginService:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginService implements Serializable {
    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";
    @Inject
    private NavigationService navigationService = null;
    @Inject
    private DAO dao = null;
    private String originalURL = "";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        if(externalContext.getRequestMap().containsKey("originalURL")) {
            this.originalURL = (String)externalContext.getRequestMap().get("originalURL");
        } else {
            this.originalURL = navigationService.externalContextRedirectToIndex();
        }  
    }

    public void doLogin() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();

        User user = dao.findUserByUsername(this.username);

        boolean validated = PasswordHasher.validatePassword(this.password, user.getPassword());

        if(user != null && validated) {
            externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
            vexternalContext.redirect(this.originalURL);
        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("False username or password!"));
        }
    }

    public void doLogout() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        externalContext.invalidateSession();
        externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + navigationService.toLogin());
    }

    // Getter and Setter
}
```

if now someone is requesting for example the "/private/test.html" my login
page appears and the user has to login. After that, if the user successfully
logged in i want to redirect to the originally requested test.html.

Now the sessionMap never has a key named "originalURL" and i always get
redirected to my index.html.

Btw my navigationservice provides two methods:

```
public String redirectToIndex() {
    return "/index.html?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String externalContextRedirectToIndex() {
    return "/Web-Tschuwwa/index.html?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The second method i had to add specially for the redirect after the login
because when i used the first method i was redirected to the index.html
of my glassfish docsroot folder. That is another thing i dont know why.
Web-Tschuwwa is the name of my project.

How can i redirect to the requested page after login?

Answer (score 0):

Oh there was a mistake in the code.....

Change this:

```
if(externalContext.getRequestMap().containsKey("originalURL")) {
    this.originalURL = (String)externalContext.getRequestMap().get("originalURL");
} else {
    this.originalURL = navigationService.externalContextRedirectToIndex();
}
```

tho this:

```
 if(externalContext.getSessionMap().containsKey("originalURL")) {
    this.originalURL = (String)externalContext.getSessionMap().get("originalURL");
} else {
    this.originalURL = navigationService.externalContextRedirectToIndex();
}
```

And it works.